# How to get Toolbar from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have `ActionBarActivity` with `NavigationDrawer` and use support_v7 `Toolbar` as ActionBar. In one of my fragments toolbar has custom view. In other fragments `Toolbar` should show title.

How get `Toolbar` instance for customizing from fragments? I can get ActionBar with `getActivity().getActionBar()`, but if I call `setTitle()` for this instance ActionBar it do nothing.

**UPD:**

In my case

`((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();`

(as MrEngineer13 said) don't work at first fragment creation because I call it from onHiddenChanged(). Now I add more one to onCreateView() and it works fine.

Comment: fragments do not have actionbars/toolbars activities do

Comment: (MainAcivity)this.getActivity()).getToolbar(); will be the right answer!! for getting the Toolbar in fragment!!

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You need to cast your activity from `getActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity` first. Here's an example:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();
```

The reason you have to cast it is because `getActivity()` returns a `FragmentActivity` and you need an `AppCompatActivity`

In Kotlin:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "My Title"
```

Comment: getting 'supportActionBar' and 'toolbar' is same thing?

Comment: @Darpan not sure

Comment: If i add this, its changing the title.. But if i go back to the parent activity, how to change the title again ? I mean i have a nav drawer. Side drawer has some fragments and main activity has its own title. When i set title of main activity, it works and in fragment, the way you mentioned worked perfect. But how should i change the title of the activity on going back?

Answer (score 85):

In case fragments should have custom view of ToolBar you can implement ToolBar for each fragment separately.

add ToolBar into fragment_layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

find it in fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //set toolbar appearance
        toolbar.setBackground(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);

        //for crate home button
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

menu listener could be created two ways:
override onOptionsItemSelected in your fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

or set listener for toolbar when create it in onCreateView():

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just want confirm this the right way to do? if we load different fragment with toolbar in viewpager+ Tablayout or Pagertabstripe it will effect the app performance while swiping?

Comment: @LOG_TAG I have a drawer design with each fragment implementing the toolbar (and thus having a toolbar in it's layout file) and the above code worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like HEYUL!! :) Btw, better to override parent Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()` instead of Fragment's, to avoid code repetition.

Comment: @ChadMx no, why he even wrote about adding toolbar in xml and so on. Author asked how to get toolbar programmatically from fragment . So http://stackoverflow.com/a/26998718/4548520 this is the best/right answer and it's short

Answer (score 51):

You have two choices to get Toolbar in fragment

First one

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

and second one

```
Toolbar toolbar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).mToolbar;
```

Comment: But is this the right way .. bcoz we have getSupportedActionBar also ?

Comment: If you are using a one-activity-to-many-fragments model, the first example simply gets you a reference to the main toolbar so you can manipulate it from your fragment.  It is also, I believe, the best option.

Answer (score 10):

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 2):

**From your Fragment:** ( get Toolbar from fragment?)

```
// get toolbar
((MainAcivity)this.getActivity()).getToolbar();  // getToolbar will be method in Activity that returns Toolbar!!  don't use getSupportActionBar for getting toolbar!!
// get action bar
this.getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

this is very helpful when you are using spinner in Toolbar and call the *spinner* or custom *views* in Toolbar from a fragment!

From your Activity:

```
// get toolbar
this.getToolbar();
// get Action Bar
this.getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: You have to have a method in your activity called **getToolbar()**, which is bad, because that is not how communication between activity and fragment should be done.

Comment: yes there is no other way for this!! many of the navigation drawer libs implement this style only !!! some times we need cast the activity because of  AppCompatActivity  (AppCompatActivity) getActivity()  that is another pain point !!! all this stuffs totally kills the dev time :(

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin users `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()`

Comment: `!!` is completly avoidable with `?` and it will save you a possible crash

Comment: I believe this is better `(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.show()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to try `getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle()` if you are using support_v7.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using these steps.

1. Set Title using below code in `onCreateView` of the main fragment.

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

2. For swapping between fragments i'm using bottom navigation bar which is implemented on `MainActivity` (Parent Activity) of the fragment. Even if you are using any button or menu item then you can change the title from `onSelectedItemClickListener`, just like i did in my case.

   ```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
       switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
           case R.id.menu_dashboard:
               getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard");
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(dashboardFragment).commit();
               active = dashboardFragment;
               return true;
           case R.id.menu_workshop:
               getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Workshops");
               fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(workshopFragment).commit();
               active = workshopFragment;
               return true;
        }
        return false;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In XML

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
 </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Kotlin: In fragment.kt 
-> onCreateView()

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)

val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.main_toolbar)

(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.show()
```

-> onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_main_menu,menu)
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
   }
```

->onOptionsItemSelected()

```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
             R.id.selected_id->{//to_do}
             else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using custom toolbar or ActionBar** and you want to get reference of your toolbar/action bar from Fragments then you need to first get instance of your Main Activity from Fragment's **onCreateView** Method like below.

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

then use activity for further implementation like below

```
ImageView vRightBtn = activity.toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_right_btn);
```

Before calling this, you need to initialize your custom toolbar in your MainActivity as below.

First set define your toolbar public like

```
public Toolbar toolbar;
public ActionBar actionBar;
```

and in **onCreate()** Method assign the custom toolbar id

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

That's It. It will work in Fragment.