# How to hide the toolbar in a ViewPager when using Scrolling RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I've got a toolbar in a view-pager (tabbed toolbar with horizontal swipe navigation) and each tab has its own fragment with a recyler_view. I now want to hide the toolbar when my recyler_view scrolls. In my fragment i added the on scroll-listener and want to call there a method in its activity class to hide the toolbar. The toolbar is created in the activity. How can I call this method from my fragment? or would it be better to implement this hiding method in my fragment itself. But then how can i "contact" my toolbar, that is created in the activity and not in the fragment. I have found solutions, but none of them talks about a recylcer_view in a fragment and view-pager for tabbed navigation. 
Would be great if you can help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998455/how-to-get-toolbar-from-fragment

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem as you and solved it by using a library [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView).

Have a look at [ViewPagerTabRecyclerViewFragment](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/samples/ViewPagerTabRecyclerViewFragment.java).

If you don't want to use a library you still can have a look at how they implemented it as the lib is Open Source