# How to remove action bar from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-coordinatorlayout

Main Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        MedSectionFragment medSectionFragment = (MedSectionFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("medSectionFragment");
        if (medSectionFragment == null){
            medSectionFragment = new MedSectionFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content, medSectionFragment, "medSectionFragment");

            // transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
          }
    }
```

First Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        //Inflate the fragment layout file
        ViewGroup rootView=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.med_sections_list, container, false);
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the fragment layout file
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.official_name_list, container, false);
}
```

after the transition from one fragment (categories) to another (sub-categories) we have listview with actionbar. its true.
[image]

But when I transition to the third fragment (detail information)

```
public class DetailMedicineFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_medicine_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
          ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      }
```

an error occurs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
>                                                                                     at
>   ua.edu.sumdu.medmaterialdesign.DetailMedicineFragment.onActivityCreated(DetailMedicineFragment.java:41)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

application style

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: The ActionBar is part of the Activity, which in turn contains the Fragment.

Comment: use a Theme with NoActionBar

Comment: how to apply theme to the fragment?

Comment: apply it to the activity hosting the fragment

Comment: if I apply style to the activity <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> action bar removed from fragments

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: There is no such thing as ActionBar in fragment...

Comment: how to hide action bar in fragment?

Comment: show us some code, we can help you then.

Answer (score 1):

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   ***Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR*** and set
>   ***windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead***

Since this question already has an answer(with above logcats) and you did that before, it should be done with these two:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

And also, since you've added a `Toolbar`, make sure the `Activity`'s `Styles` parent is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

The point is: `NoActionBar`.(like i guessed, you were using `DarkActionBar`)

Also: [Difference and uses of onCreate(), onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra)

> **onActivityCreated():**
>
> As the name states, ***this is called after*** the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` has
>   completed. It is called after `onCreateView()`, and is mainly used for
>   final initialisations (for example, modifying UI elements).

Sounds good, but, what about using this on `onCreate`?

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide()
```

It should hide the `ActionBar`.

But, about this line:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I think the problem is in the `AppCompatActivity` which you are using that in a `Fragment` i guess.

> See:
>   [How to get Toolbar from fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998455/how-to-get-toolbar-from-fragment)
>
> And this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998718/4409113

Something like it's trying to cast from that `Activity` not for that `Fragment` only.

---

And you said: **How to remove action bar from fragment?**

The thing is, why are you trying to get the `Toolbar` then?

Remember, `Fragments` doesn't have `Actionbars/Toolbars`, `Activities` has.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html